# Profiling system for "dead" code

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I recently inherited a mature SFDC organization.  It was established back in 2014 but was poorly maintained.  There is very little documentation to support the business or system requirements.  Any functional spec that exists is incomplete and out-of-date.

This system has hundreds of Apex Classes and utilizes just over 5 million characters of code.

I have begun the process of code review and I am finding plenty of code that I know is unreachable based on current business practices.  This process is long and arduous and is downright painful.  Even with this effort, I can't get any confirmation that it is not running in our production environment.

Does Salesforce provide or is there a tool available on the Marketplace that can provide code coverage/usage analysis?

Similar questions have been asked in the past, but they are quite old and I am hoping that something new has come to market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code coverage in Salesforce is focused on unit test coverage.

However, the Illuminated Cloud IDE (aka IC, a plugin for Intellij IDEA and far superior to VS Code IMHO) includes usage analysis, with call hierarchy tracing. This may be helpful for what you are doing, though you may want it to ignore test case usages to ease your effort (you could ask a question on the [IC forum](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!forum/qanda) about how to do that).